# Running drools in Databricks

Tags: java, scala, databricks, drools, azure-databricks

I am trying to implement a PoC to run Drools on Azure Databricks using Scala language. I assume  there is no equivalent python client for Drools. I am aware of other BRE python-based frameworks available which I already tested.

When trying to run a sample code in Scala notebook I keep getting the exception below.

I have imported all necessary Drools libraries.

Drools lib version: 7.1.17.0-Final

Databricks: 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)

Can somebody advise what I am doing wrong ?

Has anybody come across working example ?

I would appreciate any support.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory$LazyHolder
```

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
import org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory
import org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseFactory
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext
import org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory
import org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry

class SampleService {
    
  val resource= ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("sample.drl")
  val kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder()
  kbuilder.add(resource,ResourceType.DRL)

  val kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase()
  kbase.addPackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages())

 def runAllRulesFor(): String = {
    val session = kbase.newKieSession()
    null  
  }

}

def result = new DroolsRuleService().runAllRulesForUDF;
println(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Drools 8 without the reflective dependencies, using the static version of the engine (without reflection).

Also, to codegenerate the executable model of the rules at compile time, not at runtime.

If you can provide a reproducer of the above, feel free to share for additional support on the [drools-usage](https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage) mailing list.

Comment: Thank you @tarilabs for your feedback. Migration to Drools 8 is on my to do list. But would that solve my current issue ? Is it caused by reflection ?

Comment: Can you also share a link to the docs of the static version of the engine (Drools 8) ?

Comment: no it won't necessarily solve your problem, but given you are using Drools in a Apache Spark deployment, I mainly recommend to be sure not to "compile" the rules at runtime (I'm not experienced in Spark, but that's what I fear is happening with your snippet). If you could share the reproducer as mentioned, it would be much easier to support further